# How do I read and open files in an iOS app's documents directory?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I've copied a folder into the documents directory, and I'm able to enumerate the directory's contents, but when I check if the enumerated URL exists and is readable, I get false. How do I read and use these files?

```
let imagesURL = copyPath.appendingPathComponent("images", isDirectory: true)
guard let fileEnumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: imagesURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions()) else { return }
while let file = fileEnumerator.nextObject() {
    guard let filepath = file as? NSURL else { continue }
    print(filepath.absoluteString!)
    let isReadable = FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: filepath.absoluteString!)
    let exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filepath.absoluteString!)
    print("isReadable: \(isReadable), exists: \(exists)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`absoluteString` is the wrong API. You have to get paths in the file system with the `path` property.

And for consistency please name the URL as `fileURL`

```
...
guard let fileURL = file as? URL else { continue }
print(fileURL.path)
let isReadable = FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: fileURL.path)
let exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path)
...
```